# Get native DOM element from Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, canvas, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to manipulate a canvas but I'm not able to call `getContext` on the canvas element which I get from Webdriver:

```
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('my-canvas')).then(function (canvas) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ...
});
```

I've also tried `canvas[0]` but that doesn't work too, `getContext` is undefined. How can I reach this native canvas function ?

UPDATE: I've tried `executeScript` which works, but is extremely slow

Comment: Cam you post/attach the full HTML pls

Comment: I think that you'll need to use the executeScript...if you can show us that code, perhaps we can recognize opportunities to improve the performance.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was transferring an array of more than 7000000 elements. I reduced it, and now its fast enough!